# bibtex: upper letter in the title

Tags: bibtex, capitalization

I have this entry in bibtex:

```
@misc{ GNUCFLOW,
   author = {{GNU cflow}},
   title = "GNU cflow Documentation",
   year = "2014",
   howpublished = "http://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/"
 }
```

I want to keep the title: "GNU cflow Documentation" as it on the pdf produce but this print:

```
[GNU cflow, 2014] GNU cflow (2014). Gnu cflow documentation. http ://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/.
```

It's possible to have this or not?

Comment: in the title entry, write "{GNU} cflow Documentation".

Comment: It's work but create white space in my pdf. Anyway thank you ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you're using a bibliography style that applies "sentence style", i.e., only the first letter of the first word is capitalized, whereas all other letters are automatically set in lowercase. To override this behavior, encase the word or words in question in curly braces, i.e., write

```
title = "{GNU} cflow {Documentation}",
```

Observe that both the first and the third word of the `title` field need to be surrounded by curly braces.

Separately, you may want to load the `url` or `hyperref` package and re-write the `howpublished` field as

```
howpublished = "\url{http://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/}",
```

This will enable LaTeX to introduce linebreaks, if necessary, in the long URL string.